# Find $ \lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\sum_{j=1}^kf(b_jx+ta_j)|dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, measure-theory

Let $\,\mathrm{f}\in L^{1}\left(\,\mathbb{R}\,\right)$, and let $a_{1},\ldots,a_{k} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b_{1},\ldots,b_{k} \in 
\,\mathbb{R} - \left\{\,0\,\right\}$, assume that the numbers $a_{j}/b_{j}$ are all distinct. Determine
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left\vert\,\sum_{j = 1}^{k}\mathrm{f}\left(b_{j}x + ta_{j}\right)\right\vert
\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Source: [Last question of the real analysis qual. I took last year and barely passed (edit some typos here)](https://www.math.uci.edu/sites/math.uci.edu/files/Real%20Qual%20Spring%202016.pdf)

Some thought: If I restrict $\,\mathrm{f}$ to be non-negative the problem can be easily done by change of variable of each individual integration. Then maybe I can use the conditions to partition the real line to finite number of subsets where on each subset we know $\,\mathrm{f}_j = \,\mathrm{f}\left(b_{j}x + ta_{j}\right)$ is positive or negative.

However this is probably on the wrong track because I got $0$ point by writing them down :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: 1. It's enough to consider $L^1$ functions with compact support. For such an $f,$ the supports of the functions $f(b_jx+ta_j)$ are pairwise disjoint for large $t.$

Comment: Thank you. This is easier than I thought and I'll try to write a solution base on this later.